# Where can I specify applicationId per-combination for a multi-flavor build?

Tags: android

```
android {

    flavorDimensions 'app', 'region'

    productFlavors {
        app1 {
            dimension 'app'
        }
        app2 {
            dimension 'app'
        }
        europe {
            dimension 'region'
        }
        asia {
            dimension 'region'
        }
}
```

Now I need:

- `app1Europe` to have application id of `com.w`
- `app2Europe` to have application id of `com.x`
- `app1Asia` to have application id of
  `com.y`
- `app2Asia` to have application id of `com.z`

I can't see a place that will allow me to specify the `applicationId` per for the flavor combination.

Note: As the client app store listings already exist, I can't have one listing for these multiple regions. There really isn't any common prefix among the application ids beyond `com.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def mergedFlavor = variant.mergedFlavor
    switch (variant.flavorName) {
        case "app1Europe":
            mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.w")
            break
        case "app2Europe":
            mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.x")
            break
        case "app1Asia":
            mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.y")
            break
        case "app2Asia":
            mergedFlavor.setApplicationId("com.z")
            break
    }
}
```

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/28044024/2545800